# seeding user database with one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, seeding

I've got an MVC4 project that uses Entity Framework 5 (code-first) with code-first migrations. The site uses `SimpleMembership`. I'm attempting to seed the users table but am encountering errors relating to the setting of the navigation property.

I've got an `Account` and `User` model. `SimpleMembership` uses the `User` model as my custom `users` table. The relationship is a one-to-many with there being one `Account` per `User` but many `Users` per `Account`. I am attempting to set the `User` to `Account` relationship at seed-time but am unable to.

---

The models (extraneous properties omitted):

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Account has many users but only one "admin" user. ID manually set.
    // Nullable because of chicken / egg problem (user requires account, account requires user)
    public int? AdminUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Data.MyContext context)
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

    Account adminAccount = new Account()
    {
        Name = "Dev",
        Description = "Dev account"
    };

    context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(adminAccount);

    if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("dev@dev.com"))
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("dev@dev.com", "password", new User()
        {
            Email = "dev@dev.com",
            FirstName = "Dev",
            LastName = "Guy"
            // Problematic properties - see below
            // Account = adminAccount,
            // AccountId = adminAccount.AccountId
        });
    }
}
```

Where I appear to be running intro trouble is when I call `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount`:

1. If I attempt to include the navigation property `Account = adminAccount` I get the error:

   > `"No mapping exists from object type MyProject.Models.Account to a known managed provider native type."`
2. If I attempt to include just the FK reference `AccountId = adminAccount.AccountId` I get the error:

   > `"Invalid column name 'Account'"`
3. If I don't include `Account` or `AccountId`, I also get

   > `"Invalid column name 'Account'"`

---

I should point out that I had this working with just navigation properties in my classes. When I added foreign key properties, everything just blew up (there are errors related to FKs but I cannot reproduce them well enough to post them here and they were likely related to my database needing to be re-created. I'm seeing the above-errors with a fresh, table-less database.

Also, I'm using SQL Azure as my SQL database.

This seems like a common use case for `SimpleMembership`; I don't know what it's giving me so much trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought, it was a very silly error. Basically `Account` wasn't yet created in the database before I tried to assign its ID to the new `User`.

When I attempt to manually insert data into the database, I got the following error:

> `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Accounts_AccountId". The conflict occurred in database "projectdev", table "dbo.Accounts", column 'AccountId'.`

After some digging I found that the AccountID I was assigning to the User was incorrect, and when I changed the ID to the correct one it worked just fine. That led me to realize that I wasn't committing the Account context changes to the database before trying to assign its AccountId to the Users table.

I simply added `context.SaveChanges();` after `context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(adminAccount);` and everything worked just fine.

Good grief...